# Como clonar objeto PAINT en kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, clone, paint

Hola estoy creando un *drawable* con `canvas` en kotlin pero me gustaria reducir el código y es que tengo muchos paints:

```
        val lado=440 // preferiblemente un multiplo de 8
        val ladmit=lado/2f
        val textmed=(ladmit*resources.displayMetrics.density/4)+6
        val bitmap: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(lado, lado, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        bitmap.density=resources.displayMetrics.densityDpi
        bitmap.eraseColor(Color.argb(0,0,0,0))
        val canva = Canvas(bitmap)
        canva.drawColor(Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));
        val pback :Paint= Paint().apply {
            isAntiAlias = true
            style = Paint.Style.FILL
            color = Color.WHITE
            setShadowLayer(10f, -5f, -5f, Color.GRAY)
        }
        val pcol :Paint= Paint().apply {
            isAntiAlias = true
            style = Paint.Style.FILL
            color= "FFCC80".toInt(16) - 0xffffff
        }
        val pbord = Paint().apply {
            isAntiAlias = true
            style = Paint.Style.STROKE
            color = Color.BLACK
            strokeWidth=4f
        }
        val p = Paint().apply{
            color=Color.BLACK
            textSize=textmed
            textAlign=Paint.Align.CENTER
        }
        RectF(10f, 10f, lado-10f, lado-10f).let {
            canva.drawRoundRect(it, 25f, 25f, pback)
            canva.drawRoundRect(RectF(10f, 10f, lado-10f, ladmit), 25f, 25f, pcol)
            canva.drawRoundRect(it, 25f, 25f, pbord)
        }
        RectF(10f, ladmit/2+10f, lado/2f, lado/2f).let {
            pcol.color= Color.WHITE
            canva.drawRoundRect(it, 0f, 0f, pcol)
            canva.drawRoundRect(it, 0f, 0f, pbord)
        }
        RectF(ladmit, ladmit/2+10f, lado-10f, ladmit).let {
            pcol.color= "80CBC4".toInt(16) - 0xffffff
            canva.drawRoundRect(it, 0f, 0f, pcol)
            canva.drawRoundRect(it, 0f, 0f, pbord)
        }
        p.typeface = Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD)
        canva.drawText((Math.random() * 50).toInt().toString(), ladmit, lado*0.75f+p.textSize/(2*resources.displayMetrics.density), p)
        p.textSize= (textmed*0.6).toFloat()
        canva.drawText("001", ladmit/2, (ladmit-10f)*0.75f+p.textSize/2, p)
        canva.drawText("IZQ", ladmit, (ladmit-10f)/4+p.textSize/2, p)
        canva.drawText("01", lado*0.75f, (ladmit-10f)*0.75f+p.textSize/2, p)
        val draw:Drawable =bitmap.toDrawable(resources)
        binding.imageView.setImageDrawable(draw)
```

este es el resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

también me gustaría que el **44** fuera el único texto con negrita intente con `also{}` pero me cambia el atributo de la instancia

```
canva.drawText(..., p.also {
            it.typeface = Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD)
        })
```

alguien me podría decir como puedo clonar esta instancia de paint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clase `Paint` tiene un contructor que acepta un objeto `Paint` como parámetro y esta diseñado precisamente para clonar. Pero si además quieres ahorrarte el `apply`, puedes crear una [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#extension-functions)

```
inline fun Paint.clone(change: Paint.() -> Unit) = Paint(this).also(change)
```

El uso sería así

```
val default = Paint().apply {
    isAntiAlias = true
    color = Color.WHITE
    style = Style.FILL
    textSize = textmed
    textAlign = Align.CENTER
}
default.clone {
    color = "FFCC80".toInt(16) - 0xffffff
}
```

si quieres modificar un valor por defecto para que lo tengan las próximas instancias, simplemente cambias esa propiedad

```
default.color = Color.BLACK
```

También podrías crear un builder para cuando quieras crear sin clonar

```
inline fun paint(builder: (Paint.() -> Unit)) = Paint().also(builder)
```

y luego lo usas así

```
val default = paint {
    isAntiAlias = true
    color = Color.WHITE
    style = Style.FILL
    textSize = textmed
    textAlign = Align.CENTER
}
```

Comment: el constructor si existe pero la función estática que me escribes no

Comment: no sabia que se podían hacer extensiones a las clases como en js gracias por eso

Comment: cuál función estática? Lograste entenderlo o quieres que lo explique mejor?

Comment: me confunde un poco el `inline fun Paint.clone`

Comment: puesto que no existe una funcion estatica que se llame clone, es como si la crearas

Comment: Exacto, `fun Paint.clone` es la sintaxis para indicar que estás declarando una función llamada `clone` que va a ser una extensión de la clase `Paint`. `inline` es sólo para mejorar la performance. Le dice al compilador que no cree esa función sino que en cambio reemplaze cada una de las llamadas por el contenido de la función. Esto signifca que en tiempo de ejecución no existirá ninguna función llamada clone sino que estarás creando los objetos directamente con `Paint(this).also{}`

Comment: a listo gracias por la aclaracion

Comment: si quitas el `inline` seguirá funcionando pero clone existirá en tiempo de ejecución y será un paso más en el stack trace. Obviamente esto es una micro optimización pero de todos modos es una buena práctica para funciones de este tipo que no hacen más que llamar a otra función. Si te fijas bien, verás que ya estabas usando estas features. `apply` no es un método de la clase `Paint` sino que es una extension function y también es inline

Answer (score 0):

después de dos horas logre hacer lo que quería y aqui esta:

```
    val paintfill=(object{
        var defcol = Color.WHITE
        open inner class default : Paint() {
            init {
                    isAntiAlias = true
                    color = defcol
                    style = Style.FILL
                    textSize=textmed
                    textAlign=Align.CENTER
            }
        }
        inner class clone : default()
    })
```

esta clase anónima es capas de asignar valores por defecto a una clase y si necesitas una imagen actual del objeto simplemente llamas a clone y aquí puedes modificar lo que quieras sin alterar las demás ejemplo:

```
paintfill.clone().apply {color = "FFCC80".toInt(16) - 0xffffff}// no se modificaran las demas instancias
```

ahora que tal si quieres modificar un valor por defecto para que de hay en adelante todas las instancias lo tengan, facil, simplemente defines ese valor que puede llegar a cambiar en la clase anonima como yo hice con `defcol`:

```
paintfill.defcol = Color.BLACK // ahora todas las instancias van a tener ese valor por defecto
```